# Hanging Punchbag in Cabin - Structural

Tags: wood, roof, structural

I have a cabin at the bottom of my garden (photos attached) and am thinking about hanging a punchbag from the roof beams. I absolutely do not want the structural integrity of my cabin compromised but i was wondering if a 100lb punch bag would hang safely (and be punched) from the beams in the picture? Or if not are there any small changes I can make to increase the structural stability of the beams.

The size of the beams are 115mm x 40mm x 5000mm and there are 2 screws in each roof board with a light felt roof on the exterior.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that all there is to the roof framing? What kind of roofing?

Comment: Do you get snow there?

Comment: What is the span (from wall to wall) of the beams?

Comment: What is the thickness of the roof structure?  Maybe this is a false ceiling we’re seeing. Please a post a picture from the exterior.  It would be interesting to know how thick the roof structure is...

Comment: A picture of the attic (if any) would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not.

That's a very lightly-constructed roof by modern standards. Those "beams" are little more than stiffeners--the roofing boards are carrying most of the load over their much shorter span. By themselves the beams are not up to the task of spanning that distance with any integrity.

In my judgement any load, even static, of 100 lbs. will result in sag or other effects, and the dynamic forces of a jiggling load of such weight could pull the beam loose from the deck boards. You're also likely to see spreading of the walls due to ridge sag since there are no rafter ties preventing such movement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't even if you had better structure.   The twisting of a direct hang bag is too much for beams and joists.   I have put bags on metal I beams that were worked "loose" (have ran several gyms and boxed when younger).

If you had a 10-20 pound soft bag and you were just tapping it... maybe.   But any decent bag no way.   We have trouble hanging these in commercial places.   In fact I helped run a Gold's and the landlord took ours down and we had to get stand-up dummies.   That is what I suggest you get - anyone who wants a "punching bag" should get a stand-up bag or a hanging water bag.

Given limited space in a cabin a stand-up bag makes most sense because you could use it outside or store it outside.